# What features have been added to the Files app since it was introduced with iOS 11?

Tags: ios, files.app

As far as I'm aware, the Files app was introduced in iOS 11 and replaced the iCloud Drive app - what I can't seem to find, however, is how functionality of the app has evolved from iOS 11 to 13. Could somebody explain how the app has added features across iOS builds - for example, what changed from iOS 11 to 12, and from 12 to 13?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Files_(Apple) at least this doesn't mention any explicit updates. https://apps.apple.com/us/app/files/id1232058109 Version history is just bug fixes and feature enhancements..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS 11 introduced the Files app.

iOS 12 added the following features, summarised from

- https://support.apple.com/HT209084

  - AR Quick Look support

iOS 13 added the following features, summarised from

- https://support.apple.com/HT210393

  > - External drives supported in Files to access and manage files on a USB drive, SD card, or hard drive
  > - SMB support to connect to a server at work or a home PC
  > - Local storage for creating folders on the local drive and adding your favorite files
  > - Zip and Unzip support for creating and expanding Zip files
- https://appletoolbox.com/everything-in-the-new-files-app-for-ipados/

  - Document scanning previously only in Notes, now available to scan to Files directly.
  - Column view (iPadOS).
  - Multiple Files app windows (an iPadOS feature supported by Files app).